# Could not load images on Lambda + S3

Tags: lambda, single-page-application, aws-api-gateway

I create single page application (using Angular) and deploy to Lambda + APIGateway + S3 to render by server-side (be SEO friendly and using Express.js).
Basic functions of application work, rendering DOM dynamically and loading styles and routing, but images (PNG, JPEG) does not loaded fine excluding SVG files.

The request responses to load images have 200 status code, but images are empty and 0KB.

[image]

What should I do?
I've tried to add `*/*` to binary media types of AWS APIGateway and confirmed to exist images on S3 buckets.

Comment: Have you tried downloading those images back from S3 and opened them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codes on the server (e.g. Node.js) reject binary files, so fix it, then it works fine.

---

**For details**

At the first, the most important is set accepting binary media types.

I use The Serverless Framework to deploy this project, but binary media types are changed when deploying, so use "serverless-apigw-binary" npm package.

```
// serverless.yml
...
plugins:
  - "serverless-apigw-binary"
custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - "*/*"
...
```

Also set media types in the project entry point.

```
// app.js
...
const awsServerlessExpress = require("aws-serverless-express");
const binaryMimeTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", ...];
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app, undefined, binaryMimeTypes);

export const universal = (event, context) => {
  awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
};
```

Comment: Hi @Yohsuke. I am facing same problem as mentioned in above question. I have a node api(express) written which fetches image from S3. But with lambda and api gateway I am not able to load them. So can you explain how you solved it?

Comment: @Ananth Hi. The most important is to set accepting binary media types on API Gateway web console.
In my case, use The Serverless Framework to deploy the project, also use "serverless-apigw-binary" npm package to set binary media types for API Gateway automatically when deploying.

Comment: For details, see best answer!